# Move notes from Evernote to OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, evernote

I want to move my < 4000 notes from Evernote to Microsoft OneNote 2013. I tried the [Ever2One Converter](http://www.mobilenoter.com/Evernote) but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to move my notes in a batch?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @JulianKnight It seems that Evernote changed something in their API. Ever2One Converter can't connect to Evernote.

Comment: Ah yes, they had a major security failing recently didn't they. Hopefully Ever2One will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small tool that can do that. It's available from here:
[evernote2onenote](https://tools.stefankueng.com/Evernote2Onenote.html)

Source code is available too.

direct link to the download:
[download folder](https://github.com/stefankueng/EvImSync/releases)

Comment: Thank you for this. Any chance for an update? Microsoft's tool is no longer available either.

Comment: new version of the tool is now available (1.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that for the new versions there is an add-in for [OneNote](http://www.onenotegem.com/2/post/2013/07/onenote-import-evernote.html) called [OneNote Batch](http://www.onenotegem.com/onenote-batch.html) that will process the exported `.enex` file from Evernote over to Onenote.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote can now export to HTML. Should simplify issues like this.

You could also email all of your notes from Evernote into Outlook and go to One Note fromthere.